# How to make a Calculator that add automaticly

Tags: java, string, netbeans, int, settext

In Java, NetBeans,  I'm trying to make a calculator that adds automatically when you press a button. So for example when you hit 1 the previous amount on the calculator is added by 1. If you hit 2 the previous amount is added by 2. etc.

int a = 3;

However on the display.setText(a + display); it comes up with the error that they have to be strings, so how do I add 2 strings together?

In theory it should be 3 as display is = to 0.

How would I display the value of both the numbers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you make it so that when you press a button the value automatically adds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721210/how-can-you-make-it-so-that-when-you-press-a-button-the-value-automatically-adds)

Comment: @Lion That question was deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to cast `Strings` to `Integers` to perform math. To display the result, you'll want to convert the Integer result back to a String. For example

```
String a = "42";
String b = "6";

int addition = Integer.parseInt(a) + Integer.parseInt(b);
display.setText(Integer.toString(addition));
```

Given that this is a calculator and you know that they can only type numbers, then you should be fine converting these arbitrary Strings to numbers. But, note that in general, `Integer.parseInt()` may fail if the input is not a number.

UPDATE: basic blueprint for implementing integer calculator

```
int currentValue = 0; //at the beginning, the user has not typed anything

//here, I am assuming you have a method that listens for all the button presses, then you could
//call a method like this depending on which button was pressed
public void buttonPressed(String value) {
    currentValue += Integer.parseInt(value);
    calculatorLabelDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(currentValue));
}

//here, I am assuming there is some button listener for the "clear" button
public void clearButtonPressed() {
    currentValue = 0;
}
```

Comment: there's 9 buttons, you press a button and the value changes, you can't edit the text as it's .setEnabled(false). I'm using Swing Buttons if that makes it any clearer. I want it so that when I hit each different button he value automatically adds to the value on the display. So it's adding the value of the button every time you hit it. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You need to keep track of the previous number that was used. Then, on the next number press, add it to the previous, and set it as the new current. Etc.

Comment: I know that but how would I do it?

Comment: What did you try and what problems did you have? From the code posted here you know how to convert a string to a number and you know how to display that number. So the only thing you need to do is get the current value from the display before you add a number to it.

Comment: I need to get the updated value so that if I press another button that value would get added to the value of the button and so on so forth

Answer (score 0):

If `display` is a Swing GUI component, for example a JLabel, you cannot use it in arithmetic expressions. You can't add or substract labels or textfields. You have to do these steps:

1. Read the text input as a String
2. Convert the String into a numeric variable, e.g. Integer
3. Calculate your term using the Integer created in step (2)

You can try it like this:

```
String textFieldInput = display.getText();

int sum = 10;   // This might become a private attribute of your object instead of a local var?

int newNumber = 0;
try {
    newNumber = Integer.parseInt(textFieldInput);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Watch out: Parsing the number string can fail because the user can input anything, like for example, "lol!", which isn't a number
    System.out.println("Error while trying to parse the number input. Did you enter your name or something?!");
}

sum += newNumber;

System.out.println ("New sum = " + sum);
display.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
```

Comment: How would I do it then using Swing controls?

Comment: My code example actually suits your Swing control problem. It follows the three steps given above. First, you have to get the input from the text field, which is a String. The user might enter something like "Hello" instead of a number like 7. So the "result" of your text field isn't a number, but a String. After that, you have to try to convert the String input into a number. This might fail because the user can leave the field empty or enter trash like "hello". Then you take the converted integer, add it to a sum variable. Finally, you convert this sum back to a String and set it (.setText).